# Finding area of enclosed region of y = mx and y = $\frac {x}{x^2+10} $

Tags: definite-integrals

Homework Problem Statement:

> Any line of the form $y = mx$ will intersect the curve $y = \frac {x}{x^2+10} $ in precisely three points provided $0 < m < B$ for some number $B$. What is the value of $B$?
>
> When the line $y = mx$ intersects the curve in three points, this line and the curve $y = \frac {x}{x^2+10} $ will enclose a region consisting of two parts. Find the total area of the enclosed region. Your answer should be an expression involving $m$.

[image: graph]

For the first part, I set the above equations to equal each other to find what value of $B$ will be greater than $m$. $B$ equals $\frac {1}{10}$, therefore $0 < m < \frac {1}{10}$.

As for the second part, I am unsure of what to do. My first approach is to apply the same method from the first part, but this time, to solve for $x$. I have found that when $mx = \frac {x}{x^2+10}$, $x = \sqrt\frac {1-10m}{m}$ and $x = -\sqrt\frac {1-10m}{m}$.

The area under the curve is $A = \int f(x) - g(x)\ \textrm dx$.

From $-\sqrt\frac {1-10m}{m}$ to $0$, $f(x) = mx$ and $g(x) = \frac {x}{x^2+10} $.

From $0$ to $\sqrt\frac {1-10m}{m}$,   $f(x) = \frac {x}{x^2+10}$ and $g(x) = mx$.

After finding the area between those two, I added them together to find the total area. However, my answer was not correct.

edit: I apparently misplaced a parenthesis when inputting my answer. The answer is 10m + ln ($\frac {1}{10m$}$)-1

Comment: What was your answer, and why do you believe your answer was not correct?  The method is fine, as is the work you've shown.

Comment: By symmetry, you can integrate one side or the other, then double it.

Comment: My answer was 10m + ln($\frac {1}{10m}-1.

Comment: I am completely embarrassed. I misplaced a parenthesis when I was inputting my answer... Thanks for reassurance and help!